# Swift operators == vs ===

Tags: swift, operators, swift-playground

I have stupid question, I'm most certain, that I do something wrong, but can't figure out what it is. I have simple playground where I play with Swift Operators and came on case, where I have following code:

```
1 != 1 // false
1 !== "1".toInt() //false
1 === 1 // true
1 == "1".toInt() // true
```

Which should be perfectly fine, but the playground compiler is displaying following error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? What exactly this issue mean?

---

**Update**

When I delete the line #2, the error disappear:
[image]
**Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)**

---

**Update 2**

When I compare `1 === 1.toInt()` I got another error:
[image]

Comment: `!==` and `===` are identity operators, is 1 considered an object in *swift*?

Comment: I don't think so. But what confuse me, that line #3 in that picture is fine, but line #1 is wrong. When I delete ```1 !== "1".toInt()``` from my playground, everything is working properly. I don't see the difference. Probably I have stupid approach since I'm Ruby dev...

Comment: I updated the description to avoid these kind of questions

Comment: I'm not familiar with *swift*, but I think that in the last statement you're comparing values, and that should be fine. In the first line you're comparing references where primitives involved. Try to change `!==` to `===` and you'll get the same error.

Comment: I guess it is because `toInt` returns an "optional int", instead of an "int".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`===` is the identity operator and can only be applied to instances of *classes*,
it is declared as

```
func ===(lhs: AnyObject?, rhs: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

Now `1 === 1` works because the compiler creates `NSNumber` instances here
automatically. `NSNumber` conforms to the `IntegerLiteralConvertible`
protocol:

```
extension NSNumber : FloatLiteralConvertible, IntegerLiteralConvertible, BooleanLiteralConvertible {

    /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
    required convenience init(integerLiteral value: Int)

    /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
    required convenience init(floatLiteral value: Double)

    /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
    required convenience init(booleanLiteral value: Bool)
}
```

This can also be seen from the assembly code generated with

```
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -emit-assembly main.swift
```

which shows two calls of

```
callq   __TFE10FoundationCSo8NSNumberCfMS0_FT14integerLiteralSi_S0_
```

and demangling this function name with

```
xcrun  swift-demangle __TFE10FoundationCSo8NSNumberCfMS0_FT14integerLiteralSi_S0_
```

gives

```
ext.Foundation.ObjectiveC.NSNumber.init (ObjectiveC.NSNumber.Type)(integerLiteral : Swift.Int) -> ObjectiveC.NSNumber
```

So in `1 === 1` two instances of `NSNumber` are compared (which are objects).

Note that this works only if the Foundation framework is included (i.e., `NSNumber`
is available). Otherwise `1 === 1` fails to compile with

```
type 'AnyObject?' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
```

Both

```
1 !== "1".toInt()   // value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped
1 !== "1".toInt()!  // type 'AnyObject?' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
```

do not compile because the right-hand side is not an object and not a literal that
the compiler converts in to an object automatically. For the same reason,

```
let i = 1
1 !== i    //  type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

does not compile.

---

`==`, on the other hand, is the *equality operator* and compares the *contents* of its
operands. It is defined for optionals if the underlying type is equatable:

```
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

Therefore in `1 == "1".toInt()`, the lhs is converted to `Int?` and then compared
with the rhs.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This make perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

> *Mind you, I never programmed or even heard of Swift, but from the
>   documentation I found and the experience in C#, I try to give an
>   answer I think is correct. If not, I'll remove the answer.*

Swift seems to have (like C#) "[optional types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)", that are denoted with a question mark after to the type identifier, like this: `int?`. `toInt()` seems to [return an "optional int"](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html), which is not identical with an `int` (as shown by the error).

To make that optional int to a "normal" int, use an exclamation mark:

```
1 == "1".toInt()!
```

Answer (score 0):

The "===" operator is to test whether two object references both refer to the same object instance

In other languages, i know it is used to test if it is the same type and value.

But you called the to.Int() function on a string literal, when the code was expecting an integer literal.

I'd do it like this:

let a = "1";
let b = a.toInt()

if 1 !== b {// Do something}